# Prevent trigger of other hook_preprocess_HOOK()

Tags: theming, hooks

Is there a way to prevent other preprocess hooks from being triggered?

I have a Drupal 8 `hook_preprocess_HOOK()` implementation, and I'm doing some alterations. There will be other modules with same hook, and I need the other preprocess hooks not to alter my changes to `$variables`.

The only options I have are:

- Rely on weights system, which still could cause problems
- Set a value inside `$variables` and prevent other modules from doing their thing if the variable is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable hooks via [hook_module_implements_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.3.x).

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'preprocess_page') {
    unset($implementations['module_foo']);
    unset($implementations['module_bar']);
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with preprocess functions implemented by themes, though.

Comment: The OP asks for modules, so the response is accurate.

Comment: For themes, if the hook suggestions system is not enough, perhaps [hook_theme_registry_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/8.2.x) can do the job, by overriding the preprocess functions.

Comment: I am wondering why is is immposible to get debuger to stop and enter into
MYMODULE_module_implements_alter function to inspect values?

Comment: @MarkoBlazekovic it is because that function is called during cache clear and not page load. Try setting a breakpoint and clearing caches through UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation for Drupal 9 that makes `MYMODULE_preprocess_image_style()` run first:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 *
 * Makes MYMODULE_preprocess_image_style() run first.
 */
function MYMODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  $themeKey = 'image_style';
  if (isset($theme_registry[$themeKey]['preprocess functions'])) {
    $fname = "MYMODULE_preprocess_$themeKey";
    $pf = &$theme_registry[$themeKey]['preprocess functions'];
    $index = array_search($fname, $pf);
    if ($index) {
      unset($pf[$index]);
      array_unshift($pf, $fname);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess hooks (and specifically `hook_preprocess_page`) are not subject to `hook_module_implements_alter`, even if they are implemented by modules. However, they can be adjusted by using `hook_theme_registry_alter` as suggested by @jonhattan above. Look in the `$theme_registrary['page']['preprocess functions']` for the indexed array of implementations.

Note: Tested with Drupal 9.3.8.